# What datatype/JSON layout is AWS's LEX bot expecting when called for fulfillment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got and AWS LEX Bot and need to pull some data from a dynamoDB Table.

I created a Lambda function to do this in Java.

I'm able to successfully call the lambda function, but can't get the output to show up in the chat window.

What format/formats are expected for the response in order to get it to print properly?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ComparisonOperator;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Condition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    private static final String RESPONSE = "RESPONSE";

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, Object> request, Context context) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Map<String,String>> currentIntent = (Map<String, Map<String,String>>) request.get("currentIntent");
        Map<String, String> slots = currentIntent.get("slots");
        String countryName = slots.get("COUNTRY");
        AWSCredentials credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file.", e);
        }
        AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
        Region region = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
        dynamoDB.setRegion(region);

        HashMap<String, Condition> scanFilter = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
        Condition condition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(countryName));
        scanFilter.put("name", condition);
        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest("MigrateCountry").withScanFilter(scanFilter);
        ScanResult scanResult = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);

        String responseText;
        if (scanResult.getCount() == 0) {
            responseText = "I'm sorry, I don't have any information about "+countryName+".";
        } else {
            responseText = "Here's a fun fact about "+countryName+": "+scanResult.getItems().get(0).get("funFact")+".";
        }
        context.getLogger().log("RESPONSE: "+responseText);
        return responseText;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response format is available in the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format).

Example for the documentation:

```
"dialogAction": {
  "type": "Close",
  "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled or Failed",
  "message": {
    "contentType": "PlainText or SSML",
    "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."
  },
 "responseCard": {
    "version": integer-value,
    "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
    "genericAttachments": [
        {
           "title":"card-title",
           "subTitle":"card-sub-title",
           "imageUrl":"URL of the image to be shown",
           "attachmentLinkUrl":"URL of the attachment to be associated with the card",
           "buttons":[ 
               {
                  "text":"button-text",
                  "value":"Value sent to server on button click"
               }
            ]
         } 
     ] 
   }
}
```

Note a number of these fields can be left blank if you are not using them.